# Can i use this syntax in ORACLE ?(SUM(CA.DEPT)=SUM(CA.RECEIVABLE)

Tags: oracle, function, sum

Can I use this syntax in ORACLE? `SUM(CA.DEPT)=SUM(CA.RECEIVABLE)`
I need to take where total dept and total receivable are equal. If it is wrong what I can use instead of this?

```
SELECT CA.DEPT,CA.RECEIVABLA 
FROM CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT CA
  INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_BACKUP CB
          ON CA.C_CODE=CB.C_CODE 
WHERE  SUM(CA.DEPT)=SUM(CA.RECEIVABLE)
```

Comment: `GROUP BY + HAVING` alternatively `GROUP BY` + WHERE but wrapped with subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it is wrong what I can use instead of this?

This is one method

```
SELECT
    ca.dept,
    ca.receivabla
FROM
    customer_account ca
    INNER JOIN customer_backup cb ON ca.c_code = cb.c_code
GROUP BY
    ca.dept,
    ca.receivabla
HAVING SUM(ca.dept) = SUM(ca.receivable)
```